# Changing the launch icon

Tags: java, swing, icons

I would like to replace the java launch icon:

[image]

I am starting my application via spring and put my icon here inside:

[image]

I am starting my gui like that my `MainWindow` extends a `JFrame`:

```
/**
 * starts the GUI
 */
public void start() {               
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MainWindow.class.getResource("icon.png"));
            makeLayout();   
        }
    });
}
```

However the icon does not change. Any recommendation what I could do?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage()` returns an image, but you are not doing anything with it.  You need to use `setIconImage()`.  Try this...

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
    MainWindow.class.getResource("icon.png")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL(path);
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image img = kit.createImage(url);
getFrame().setIconImage(img);
```

The URL can throw MalformedUrlException. If so happens,  then just replace the first line with this

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(path);
```

Comment: Btw the last line does not work in my case cause I am in my class MainWindow(). Any suggestion?

Comment: You need the reference of the JFrame that is shown up. I think your MainWindow extends JFrame then just try setIconImage*img)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your path needs to include the "/resources/" part. so it would look like this:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MainWindow.class.getResource("resources/icon.png"));
```